# Cart checkout issue in Spree - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

## Steps to produce the issue

Login as user

Add product to the cart

Remove the product from the cart (Product is removed from the cart )

But , the product id still exist in the checkout button in the cart
page [modal] , causing error ...

For Instance ,

I have 3 items in my cart with product id's - '400' ,' 401' ,' 402' .
Even if i remove the item '400' from the cart.. The checkout form action results in the query as below

```
SELECT spree_line_items.* FROM spree_line_items WHERE spree_line_items.order_id = 195 AND spree_line_items.id IN (400, 401, 402) ORDER BY spree_line_items.created_at ASC .
```

And this causes the error page
[image]